# Multidatacenter consistency

Tags: cassandra, datastax

WIth multi data center, do we have a option where the consistency can be tuned to check the latest data in both the data centers before fetching data? like one, quorom or All is specific to data center. Can we do the same to check consistency of the data in both data centers? If we have replication factor 3 and 3 for both data centers. Does each_quorum solve this issue or we have consistency level ALL where it checks consistency in 6 nodes in both dcs'?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html), `EACH_QUORUM` achieves this:

> Used in multiple data center clusters to strictly maintain
>   consistency at the same level in each data center. For
>   example, choose this level if you want a read to fail when
>   a data center is down and the QUORUM cannot be reached on
>   that data center.

Answer (score 1):

`EACH_QUORUM` is *probably* what you want, but unfortunately, `EACH_QUORUM` for reads is not supported anymore: see [this topic](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/topic/java-driver-user/DeJvBs4qinY/discussion) on the Java driver mailing list for an explanation.

If your writes are done with `EACH_QUORUM` or higher, then simply do your reads with `LOCAL_QUORUM` and you will achieve the desired consistency level. If not, you will have to read with consistency `ALL`, at the (very likely) risk of having some of your reads fail if not all replicas in both DCs are alive.